# How to remove tabs in Android Activities

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, removeall

I am using tab hosts in my app as:[image]

When i click on any tab i move to another activity as follows:
[image]

I want to remove tabs from screen when I click on any tab except the main tab button. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try{
    Resources ressources = getResources(); 
     TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

    // Main tab
    Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, DasashboardActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("Main")
        .setIndicator("Main", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
        .setContent(intentAndroid);
    tabHost.clearAllTabs();


    // Log tab

    Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, LogActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("Log")
        .setIndicator("Log", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_email))
        .setContent(intentApple);



    // Settings tab
    Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecWindows = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("Settings")
        .setIndicator("Settings", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_brightness_high))
        .setContent(intentWindows);

    // Help tab
    Intent intentBerry = new Intent().setClass(this, HelpActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecBerry = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("Help")
        .setIndicator("Help", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_help))
        .setContent(intentBerry);

    // add all tabs 
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecWindows);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecBerry);

    //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("ERROR in Log class", ex.toString());
    }
  }


}
```

How can I remove the tabs from other launched activities?

Comment: wt u want to achive ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling one activity and adding Tabs to the Activity. See this for example:

```
Intent intentBerry = new Intent().setClass(this, HelpActivity.class);
TabSpec tabSpecBerry = tabHost
    .newTabSpec("Help")
    .setIndicator("Help", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_help))
    .setContent(intentBerry);
```

Use this instead to create only the Activity, but without tabs:

```
Intent intentBerry = new Intent().setClass(this, HelpActivity.class);
startActivity(intentBerry);
```

Comment: Thanks ElectronicGeek :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want achieve, but removing tabs from the tabview is certainly not allowed and its not good either. so the best way i can suggest you disabling tabs which has dependency on some other tabs. Like a user has to go through `Tab A` before `Tab B` then disable `Tab B` first time and enable it when `Tab A` contents is watched.

enabling tabs

```
findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost).getCurrentTabView().setEnabled(true);
```

disabling tabs

```
findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost).getCurrentTabView().setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: when i click on any tabs i.e if i click on help then there should not be tabs on the top of help activity ,sush i don't know how to do it :|

Comment: @user3381979 tabs are not meant for that, i.e to disappear when other tabs are clicked, however u can disable some tabs for some specific validation  .